# Refresh Div with Jquery at fixed time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh

I've got a php script that tells me when the next bus is due, and at the moment I'm refreshing this into a div, using jquery, every minute or so. Now, because I know the time at which the data will change (after the bus has come), I want it to refresh the div at this time (or just after, doesn't really matter).

I should point out that I'm fairly new to js, but this is what I've got so far:

```
    var nextbustime = $('#bus').contents();
var nextbustime = new Date(nextbustime);
var now = new Date();

var t = nextbustime.getTime() - now.getTime();


var refreshId = setTimeout(function()
{
    $('#bus').fadeOut("slow").load('modules/bus.php?randval='+ Math.random()).fadeIn("slow");
}, t);
```

The div is loaded originally with a php include. Naturally, what I've done doesn't work at all.

Do I need some loops going on? Do I need to refresh the time calculator?

Please please help!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What value does `nextbustime` take (when you first set it)? Also note that the second `var` shouldn't be there -- you're not redeclaring the variable, just changing it's value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery anyways, check out this jQuery plugin here: [jQuery timer plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers)

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your statements that the code works for the first refresh?  What you need to do is handle the next several.  Since the time may vary (it appears), `setInterval` probably won't work for you.  What should work is calling your function again at the end of each timeout.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    changeToNextBus();
});

function changeToNextBus() {
    var nextbustime = $('#bus').contents();
    var nextbustime = new Date(nextbustime);
    var now = new Date();

    var t = nextbustime.getTime() - now.getTime();

    var refreshId = setTimeout(function()
    {
        $('#bus').fadeOut("slow").
                  load('modules/bus.php?randval='+ Math.random()).
                  fadeIn("slow");
        changeToNextBus();
    }, t);
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work on the first refresh, which is part of the problem...
And I just tried what you suggested (and variations of), and it causes a big ol' loop...

Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Ben C, is the value of t correct for the number of seconds at which you want the refresh?  I'm unsure how you are going to do this without a loop - isn't that the point?  You just need the loop to happen only at a set interval.

Also, is the JavaScript that's getting loaded in the bus.php?  Or is it elsewhere?  My code assumed elsewhere.